# azure pipelines.yml using a vm with azure cli and python 3?

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, devops

i am making an azure pipeline with .yml  to:
1) clone my repo 
2) run a script in the repo that will copy a file from the repo into a datalake folder

currently the example  for the pipeline comes with 
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04'

but my script has import azure and fails,  i could make a step in the .myl with

```
pip install azure
```

but adds more time,  i read that the vms are been pull from dockerhub,  is there a vm with azure cli and python 3?   and how should i use it?
i found https://hub.docker.com/r/azuresdk/azure-cli-python#docker  but i try to put it like

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'azure-cli-python'
```

or

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'azuresdk/azure-cli-python'
```

but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

you can only use predefined vm images, more over, you are confusing containers with vm images. you can use containers to run build jobs:

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: inflation
    image: azuresdk/azure-cli-python
jobs:
  - job: job_name
    container: inflation
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04' # needed for linux containers to work
```

Comment: so the vmImage is the virtual machine,  and inside that vm the docker container will run,    in your example means: a vm with ubuntu 16.04  and inside a docker container azuresdk/azure-cli-python will run,  and that what ultimately the yml will use for the steps?

Comment: steps you need to add to this yaml as well. but yes. if you do this, all the steps will run inside the container

Answer (score 0):

just in case some one else have a problem like this here is how i did it with the steps =)
thanks to 4c74356b41

```
resources:
  containers:
  - container: inflation
    image: azuresdk/azure-cli-python
jobs:
  - job: job_name
    container: inflation
    pool:
      vmImage: 'Ubuntu-16.04' # needed for containers to work
    steps:
      - script: python --version
        displayName: "python --version"
```